# How to save bitmap to particular internal storage location in android app

Tags: java, android, image

The following is my code. I'm trying to get a bitmap I create into the files folder so I can display it in a gallery. Any clue as a better way of/location to doing this or where my program is running into problems?

```
        try{
            BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) mimageView.getDrawable();
            Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
            File directory = new File("data/data/com.example.feedme/files");
            if (!directory.exists()){
                directory.mkdirs();
            }
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = Record.this.openFileOutput(directory.toString(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fileOutputStream);
            fileOutputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.w("BitMapError", "Bitmap was not saved right");

        }
```

Comment: You cannot use open FileOutput on a directory.

Comment: `Log.w("BitMapError", "Bitmap was not saved right");` Change to `Log.w("BitMapError", "Exception: "+ e.getMessage());`

Comment: `File directory = new File("data/data/com.example.feedme/files");` Change to `File directory = getFilesDir();`

Comment: `if(!directory.mkdirs()) return;`

Comment: @blackapps Don't answer in comments. Make a proper answer instead. 